# Running BigQuery Standard SQL with external UDF library

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BigQuery feature of including external libraries when running UDF, using standard SQL.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunc(a FLOAT64, b STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS
"""
    return doInterestingStuff(a, b);
"""
OPTIONS (
  library="gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib1.js"
);

SELECT myFunc(3.14, 'foo');
```

For lib1.js below I have:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION doInterestingStuff(a FLOAT64, b STRING)
      RETURNS STRING
      LANGUAGE js AS
    """
        return a*2;
    """;
```

When running this I get an error:

```
Unexpected identifier at gs://my-bucket/path/to/lib1.js line 1, columns 7-16
```

What is the expected structure of the included library file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `lib1.js` need to be JavaScript, not a SQL statement. In your case the contents should be:

```
function doInterestingStuff(a, b) {
  return a * 2;
}
```